# Are all Infiniband CX4 cables work the same (support both SDR and DDR rate)?

Tags: infiniband

Are all Infiniband CX4 cables work the same (support both 10Gb SDR and 20Gb DDR rate)?
Or actually there are some kind of standards only some CX4 cables can do 20Gb DDR?

Same question goes for 40Gb QDR and 56Gb FDR QSFP cables.